# User authentication will not work in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have been trying to add user authentication to my social media/blog app in django. This code returns an error "UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username". Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Any helpful advice would be great.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def sign_up(request):
    context = {"form": SignUpForm}

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

            user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password)
            user = form.save(commit=False)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, "sign_up/sign_up.html", context)
```

Comment: It means there already exists a `User` with that `username`...

Comment: But you are also not properly creating users: you need to *hash* the passwords.